# Declare all dependencies in a Marionette+RequireJS application before Application is created

Tags: javascript, architecture, requirejs, marionette

I'm building a new application using Marionette and RequireJS, and I've got the following structure:

```
/main.js -- Main require() call that includes app.js and calls Application.start()
/app.js -- Application definition
/modules
    /sub
        /controller.js -- Defines a sub-application, requires app.js
    ...
```

I'm trying to keep dependencies at the top level of each file, as opposed to using `require()` inline, so that the `r.js` compiler can find them. The problem is, in my `controller.js` file, I am requiring `app.js` (in order to add initializers) and so I cannot require `controller.js` in `app.js` until **after** the Application has initialized, which means I can't put `controller` in the top-level `define()` array.

A simplified example of the currently working code:

```
// app.js
define(['marionette'], function(Marionette) {
    var Application = new Marionette.Application();
    Application.on("initialize:after", function() {
        require(['modules/sub/controller'], function() {
            Backbone.history.start();
        });
    });
});

// controller.js
define(['app'], function(Application) {
    Application.module('SubApplication', function(SubApplication, Application, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
        var router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
            appRoutes: { "foo": "bar" }
        });
        var controller = { foo: function() {} };
        Application.addInitializer(function() {
            new router({ controller: controller });
        });
    });
});
```

I'm still fairly new to both Require and Marionette, so any suggestions would be welcome! I do know that I can include the files I want via the `include` option to `r.js`, but I thought this question was worth asking nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've chosen to do it in my [book on Marionette and RequireJS](https://leanpub.com/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette/) is to require inline the modules that are only necessary for a subset of functionality. This simplifies development, and also means that modules won't be loaded unless that code path is triggered.

R.js will find inline dependencies just fine (provided they're defined as strings, i.e. not computed dynamically). In addition, they will also work with [Almond.js](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) (but don't forget to use the `findNestedDependencies` option in your build file).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, David - I'm actually reading through both your books right now, but hadn't really gotten into the RequireJS one yet. :) Good to know that r.js works with inline dependencies - that wasn't clear to me from the documentation.